# How to get the URL for a specific app in .net maui?

Tags: c#, maui

I am trying to open a specific app using its URL scheme in my maui application. For example I found this on microsoft learn: await Launcher.Default.OpenAsync("lyft://ridetype?id=lyft_line"); this works however i am not sure how to get the URL for other apps.

I have tried to copy the link from the playstore but it just opens the details page of that app in the playstore.

Comment: You just have to research.  There are various sites that have attempted to curate list of known url schemes, but there is no exhaustive master list.

Comment: As I said I want to open a specific app but I found nothing related to a url scheme. So i wondered if there was a way to get it.

Comment: Are you looking for the method to open other app by using the url? You can refer to this [Open another app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/launcher?tabs=macios#open-another-app) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, not all apps have a URL scheme that is publicly available or documented, so you may need to do some research to find it.

To find an app's URL scheme, search online for the app name and "URL scheme" or "deep link", or use a tool like Charles Proxy or Wireshark to sniff network traffic while using the app.